# Using onDraw() in Subclass of TextView Not Working in Honeycomb

Tags: android, textview

I have an object thats subclassed from `TextView`.

I am trying to draw a blue line when a variable is true in the `onDraw()` method of my custom `TextView`.

**My Code**

```
       if (this._selected) {
            this.bluePaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionBlue));
            float pix = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 6, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            this.bluePaint.setStrokeWidth(pix);
            canvas.drawLine(0,this.getHeight()-(pix/2),this.getWidth(),this.getHeight()-(pix/2),this.bluePaint);
            Log.d("CCTab","Tab Height:"+this.getHeight()+" Width:"+this.getWidth()+" StrokeWidth:"+pix);
        }
```

Now this works in Eclair (2.1, API level 7) however it doesn't work in Gingerbread (2.6 & 2.7, API level 9 & 10).

**My Question**

Why?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a solution to this problem. However as a workaround instead of using the TextView to extend my class from I used View and implemented the drawing of the text manually as well as drawing this line and that has worked.